# SQL Alchemy hybrid_property with stored procedure

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLalchemy with postgresql, and wrote a procedure on my database, called `calculate_validation_for_file(self.versionId)`

Now, I want to write a hybrid_property that would automatically call this function in my selects.

In a form like
`SELECT name, id, calculate_validation_for_file(versionId) as isValid, deleted FROM my_table`

I tried the following code, but I get an error:

```
@hybrid_property
def isValid(self):
    return func.calculate_validation_for_file(self.versionId)
```

But this returns an error:
`Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: <Function instance>`

I also tried with

```
@hybrid_property
def isValid(self):
    return select(func.calculate_validation_for_file(self.versionId))
```

But then I get the error: `Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: <Select instance>`

So how do I write a hybrid_property using a stored procedure within my database?

Comment: Does your code correctly use the decorator? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add them here as well. edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this value is in your database, and not in your mapper's dictionary, this attribute is more appropriately stored as a [`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property), which will  map a SQL expression to your class:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
from sqlalchemy import select, func

class Version(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'version'

    versionId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    isValid = column_property(
        func.calculate_validation_for_file(self.versionId)
    )
```

> Note: some of the neat semantic arguments are possible due to [SqlAlchemy being smart](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#composing-from-column-properties-at-mapping-time).

Comment: I added this to the code:
`isValid = column_property(
        select(func.calculate_validation_for_file(
            versionId)).scalar_subquery()
    )`
but the error is now: `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` because it compiles into: `SELECT (SELECT calculate_validation_for_file(my_table."versionId") AS calculate_validation_for_file_1 
FROM s3_object_version) AS anon_1 FROM my_table`

Comment: It worked without the `select` statement. Thank you!

Comment: I'll edit accordingly.